# jquery 'option' appending issue with select object

Tags: jquery

i am  making a select object as well appending the options, everything going well. but the options never appending to select object.. any help?

```
if (el.type === 'select') {
    element = $('<label>' + el.label + '<select></select></label>').attr({
        id: el.id,
        name: el.name
    }) //my select object
    var options = ""
    $.map(el.options, function(option, i) {
        options += '<option' + option.value + '>' + option.text + '</option>';
    })
    $(element).append(options); // never append to select object
    console.log(options); //it prints properly like : <option>Select Country</option><optionin>India</option><optionus>United Stated</option><optionuk>United Kingdom</option><optioncn>Canada</option>
}​
```

what would be the issue then? anything wrong?

Comment: You're appending to the label, not the select.  use `$(element).find('select').append(options);`.  BTW, `$.map` is for returning an array of values, `$.each` is for iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me, did you check the select object that you created and did not insert into the DOM for the changes ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7WTS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, i appended with this way, it work well..

```
if(el.type === 'select'){
                        element = $('<label>'+el.label+'<select></select></label>').attr({
                            id : el.id,
                            name:el.name
                        })
                        var options = ""
                        $.map(el.options, function (option,i) {
                            $(element).find('select').append($('<option></option>').attr('value',option.value).text(option.text));
                        })

                    }
```